# Javascript Canvas Animation (Stick Figure Movement)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have been looking everywhere for a place to show how to do animation. I have seen where you can move blocks to one area and back, a circle up and down, but nothing as to a figure moving his body. I use css animation, but wanted to try the javascript canvas. Is there any way this figure can do a waving animation on Canvas? I'm assuming that setTimeout will be needed?

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px" >
Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas element
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get Canvas Context object

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "black"; // #000000
context.arc(200.width, 50, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.fill(); //fill the circle  

context.beginPath(); 
context.lineWidth = 6;
context.stroke();

//body
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(200, 80);
context.lineTo(200, 180);
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();

//arms
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(150, 130);
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(250, 130);
context.stroke();

//legs
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(200, 180);
context.lineTo(150, 280);
context.moveTo(200, 180);
context.lineTo(250, 280);
context.stroke();
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, since we're going to be drawing a frame over and over we need to put the drawing code into a `draw function`.

There is a method on the Window object called `requestAnimationFrame` that will consistently call this `draw` function whenever it is available to. This prevents the window from using up all your memory and will pause the animation if you flip tabs while the animation is running. `setTimeout` and `setInterval` used to be utilized for this, but **don't** use them anymore.

Since all that is happening is that the `draw` function is consistently called, in order to only change the drawing periodically we set a variable (in this case called `wave`) that determines how the arm is drawn.

The `timestamp` is used to determine if 900 milliseconds have passed since the last drawing was made whenever `draw` is called. if it hasn't we keep calling the function until that duration has passed. Normally we would want this to be faster but since we're using a 'wave' as an example and we only have two drawing states( up or down ) it works fine.

```
let timestamp = Date.now();
let wave = false;


draw();
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get Canvas Context object
let timestamp = Date.now();
let wave = false;


draw();

function draw() {
if(Date.now() < (timestamp+900)) return requestAnimationFrame(draw);

context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "black"; // #000000
context.arc(200, 50, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.fill(); //fill the circle  

context.beginPath(); 
context.lineWidth = 6;
context.stroke();

//body
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(200, 80);
context.lineTo(200, 180);
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();

//arms
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(150, 130);
if(wave) { 
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(250, 130);
wave = false;
}
else {
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(250, 70);
wave = true;
}
context.stroke();

//legs
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(200, 180);
context.lineTo(150, 280);
context.moveTo(200, 180);
context.lineTo(250, 280);
context.stroke();
timestamp = Date.now();
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px" >
Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas element
</canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect! Excellent explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Are there ways to do more? Do you have website examples? What if I wanted him to jump and wave, then walk to the right? I can make another question if you want me to to give you more reputation. @zfrisch