# Animate Canvas from Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119527/6437335), which draws and animates a stick figure, into Vue.

```
   draw(timestamp, wave) {
        if(Date.now() < (timestamp+900)) return requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);

        context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "black"; // #000000
        context.arc(200, 50, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.fill(); //fill the circle  

        context.beginPath(); 
        context.lineWidth = 6;
        context.stroke();

        //body
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(200, 80);
        context.lineTo(200, 180);
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.stroke();

        //arms
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.moveTo(200, 100);
        context.lineTo(150, 130);
        if(wave) { 
        context.moveTo(200, 100);
        context.lineTo(250, 130);
        wave = false;
        }
        else {
        context.moveTo(200, 100);
        context.lineTo(250, 70);
        wave = true;
        }
        context.stroke();

        //legs
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.moveTo(200, 180);
        context.lineTo(150, 280);
        context.moveTo(200, 180);
        context.lineTo(250, 280);
        context.stroke();
        timestamp = Date.now();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get Canvas Context object
    let timestamp = Date.now();
    let wave = false;

    this.draw(timestamp, wave);
}
```

If I do the entire draw method inside of my `mounted` method, it works. But when I move draw to it's own method, as shown above, it fails.

I know it's failing because the line `if(Date.now() < (timestamp+900))` is always returning false when running the code above. But I'm not sure why that's happening, or what the difference is.

How can I get this canvas to animate?

Comment: It may not know what `context` is because it is defined within the scope of your mounted function and not passed into the draw function.

Comment: @Bryan thanks! I'm not getting any errors, and it draws the figure, it just doesn't animate the arm

Comment: Can you clarify if your draw function is a computed property or a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how this might look in a component.

```js
Vue.component('canvas-demo', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            wave: false
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        this.startDrawing(this.$el.getContext("2d"));
    },
    template: '<canvas></canvas>',
    methods: {
        startDrawing: function(context) {
            var draw = () => {
                if (Date.now() < (this.timestamp + 900)) return requestAnimationFrame(draw);

                context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "black"; // #000000
                context.arc(200, 50, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.fill(); //fill the circle  

                context.beginPath();
                context.lineWidth = 6;
                context.stroke();

                //body
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(200, 80);
                context.lineTo(200, 180);
                context.strokeStyle = "black";
                context.stroke();

                //arms
                context.beginPath();
                context.strokeStyle = "black";
                context.moveTo(200, 100);
                context.lineTo(150, 130);
                if (this.wave) {
                    context.moveTo(200, 100);
                    context.lineTo(250, 130);
                    this.wave = false;
                }
                else {
                    context.moveTo(200, 100);
                    context.lineTo(250, 70);
                    this.wave = true;
                }
                context.stroke();

                //legs
                context.beginPath();
                context.strokeStyle = "black";
                context.moveTo(200, 180);
                context.lineTo(150, 280);
                context.moveTo(200, 180);
                context.lineTo(250, 280);
                context.stroke();
                this.timestamp = Date.now();
                requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            }

            draw();
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <canvas-demo></canvas-demo>
</div>
```